# Statistics 60 duels found between two people

Tags: probability, distributions

It's been a long time since I took stats, and I'm forgetting a good way to explain this.  Friend and I fought 60 duels.   I won 40, he won 20.    He's upset.

I'm trying to explain to him that our skill level is pretty close to the same and that its probable that it was just a bad outcome, and within a standard range of chance.

How can I show this more academically?

Comment: Usually all that matters is who won the first one.  There usually aren't any more duels after that. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the binomial distribution.

Suppose the probability of winning is $p=\frac12$, which it is if you indeed have the same skill level.

Call the number of wins for you $X$.

Then $P(X \geq 40) = 1-P(X \leq 39) = 1-F(39;60,\frac12)\approx0.0067$.

I'm sorry, but stats aren't really on your side.

However, suppose you are a little better, and your probability of winning is $p=0.6$. Then $P(X \geq 40) = 1-P(X \leq 39) = 1-F(39;60,0.6)\approx0.179$. Maybe you can tell him this. You can use [this online calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) to calculate with other values for $p$.

Comment: If the duels are independent and identically distributed, then sure. But, if there is substantial autocorrelation (e.g. if the true model were a binomial model with autoregressive normally distributed random effects on the logit scale), that $.0067$ would be much larger. Such as effect seems plausible, because the person who's on a losing streak seems to have a lower probability of winning the next match up, e.g. due to being demoralized or deciding to use a higher risk strategy (which would actually make them not identically distributed)

Comment: @not_least_squares A simple story to generate correlated error in computer gaming is to blame the outcome on the mouse. "The mouse I played those 60 games with had horrible precision, was all jerky, ...*whine*" :P